Mirth 4.5.0 JSON parse FHIR resources error using Hapi FHIR 7.2.0
JSON parse fails on the Appointment resource, which is similar to the JSON parse Patient resource example in the Hapi FHIR docs. JSON parse of FHIR resources works in plain old Java. This fails with Mirth 4.5.0, Java 17, Hapi FHIR 7.2.0, and Windows. I expect an Appointment object to be returned when the JSON Appointment resource is parsed. I can successfully JSON parse a Patient resource. This also fails for the Encounter resource. Mirth uses Rhino.js to translate JavaScript to Java. I am able to successfully use Hapi FHIR 6.8.7 as a workaround.
JavaScript destination connector:
// Create a HAPI FHIR context for FHIR
var context = new Packages.ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext.forR4();
// Instantiate a new parser
var parser = ctx.newJsonParser();

var input = {
{
"resourceType" : "Appointment",
"status" : "booked"
};

// Parse it
var appointment = parser.parseResource(Packages.org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Appointment, JSON.stringify(input));

Stack trace:
DETAILS:    Wrapped ca.uhn.fhir.context.ConfigurationException: HAPI-1716: Resource class[org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Appointment] does not contain any valid HAPI-FHIR annotations
    at 580496cb-4e73-4584-b43b-2d157216edf7_JavaScript_Writer_9:494 (doScript)
    at 580496cb-4e73-4584-b43b-2d157216edf7_JavaScript_Writer_9:519
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1899) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:160) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:226) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1692) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1013) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:109) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:412) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3578) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:121) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.executeScript(JavaScriptTask.java:151) ~[mirth-server.jar:?]
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.js.JavaScriptDispatcher$JavaScriptDispatcherTask.doCall(JavaScriptDispatcher.java:261) ~[js-server.jar:?]
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.js.JavaScriptDispatcher$JavaScriptDispatcherTask.doCall(JavaScriptDispatcher.java:221) ~[js-server.jar:?]
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:114) ~[mirth-server.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[?:?]
Caused by: ca.uhn.fhir.context.ConfigurationException: HAPI-1716: Resource class[org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Appointment] does not contain any valid HAPI-FHIR annotations
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.ModelScanner.scan(ModelScanner.java:232) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.2.0.jar:?]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.ModelScanner.init(ModelScanner.java:141) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.2.0.jar:?]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.ModelScanner.<init>(ModelScanner.java:98) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.2.0.jar:?]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext.scanResourceTypes(FhirContext.java:1064) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.2.0.jar:?]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext.scanResourceType(FhirContext.java:1041) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.2.0.jar:?]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext.getResourceDefinition(FhirContext.java:500) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.2.0.jar:?]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.parser.BaseParser.parseResource(BaseParser.java:679) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.2.0.jar:?]
    at ca.uhn.fhir.parser.BaseParser.parseResource(BaseParser.java:738) ~[hapi-fhir-base-7.2.0.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:138) ~[rhino-1.7.13.jar:1.7.13]
    ... 15 more

